# Data.Table: Error in my code when rearranging data --R

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to rearrange my data from this:

```
 Type Student Rt1 Rt2 Rt3 Rt4 Rt5 Rt6 Rt7 Rt8 Rt9 Rt10 Rt11
1:  SNR  789331 3.6 3.8 4.0 4.2 3.4 2.4 3.0 3.2 3.2  3.6  4.0
2:  SNR  805933 4.8 4.0 4.0 3.6 3.2 3.2 3.2 3.2 NaN  NaN  3.2
3:  SNR  826523 4.4 4.2 4.2 4.4 4.6 4.6 NaN 4.6 NaN  4.2  4.2
4:  SNR  832929 3.8 3.8 3.8 4.0 3.6 NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
5:  SNR  838607 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 4.4 4.2 4.4 3.8  NaN  3.6
6:  SNR  841903 3.2 4.2 4.2 NaN 3.6 NaN 4.0 3.4 4.2  NaN  4.6
```

to this:

```
  Student Type timePeriod  week Rating
1  789331  SNR        Rt1 Jan11    3.6
2  805933  SNR        Rt1 Jan11    4.8
3  826523  SNR        Rt1 Jan11    4.4
4  832929  SNR        Rt1 Jan11    3.8
5  838607  SNR        Rt1 Jan11    5.0
6  841903  SNR        Rt1 Jan11    3.2
```

Below is the code I have been trying to use. It is making the columns and everything fine, but the Ratings that it is assigning are incorrect. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
  pulse1<-NULL
  timePeriods<-c("Rt1", "Rt2", "Rt3", "Rt4", "Rt5", "Rt6", "Rt7", "Rt8", "Rt9", "Rt10", "Rt11")
  weeks<-c("Jan11","Jan25","Feb1","Feb8", "Feb15", "Mar1", "Mar8", "Mar15","Mar22", "Mar29", "Apr5")
  measureType<-c("Time", 11)

  for (columnNumber in 1:11)
  {
    temp.data<-data.frame(Student=pulse$Student, Type=pulse$Type, 
                          timePeriod=timePeriods[columnNumber], week=weeks[columnNumber], 
                          Rating=pulse[, columnNumber+2])
    pulse1<-rbind(pulse1, temp.data)  
  }
```

The output that this code is producing is:

```
 Student Type timePeriod  week Rating
1  789331  SNR        Rt1 Jan11      3
2  805933  SNR        Rt1 Jan11      3
3  826523  SNR        Rt1 Jan11      3
4  832929  SNR        Rt1 Jan11      3
5  838607  SNR        Rt1 Jan11      3
6  841903  SNR        Rt1 Jan11      3
```

Thank you!!!
I have attached my data below:

```
> dput (pulse)
structure(list(Type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("FYS", "SNR"), class = "factor"), Student = c(789331L, 
805933L, 826523L, 832929L, 838607L, 841903L, 843618L, 852125L, 
876406L, 879972L, 885650L, 888712L, 903303L, 796882L, 827911L, 
830271L, 831487L, 834598L, 836364L, 839802L, 855524L, 873527L, 
885409L, 894218L, 928026L, 932196L, 955389L, 956952L, 957206L, 
957759L, 959200L, 962490L, 968728L, 969005L, 971179L, 976863L, 
981621L, 952797L, 965873L, 967416L, 975424L), Rt1 = c(3.6, 4.8, 
4.4, 3.8, 5, 3.2, 4.4, 3.2, 3.6, 3.8, 4, 4.4, 3.6, NaN, NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
4, 3.8, 3, NaN, 3.6, NaN, 4.4, NaN, NaN, 3.6, 3.4, 4.2, NaN), 
    Rt2 = c(3.8, 4, 4.2, 3.8, 5, 4.2, 4.4, NaN, 4, 3.8, 4.4, 
    4, 3.8, 4.4, 4.2, 4.6, 4.4, 5, 4, 3.4, 5, 3.8, 4.8, 4.4, 
    4.6, 3.2, 5, 4.2, 4.4, 4.4, 3.4, 3.8, 3.8, 3.6, 4.8, 4.4, 
    4.8, NaN, 4.75, NaN, 4), Rt3 = c(4, 4, 4.2, 3.8, 5, 4.2, 
    4.6, 3.8, 4.2, 3.8, 4, NaN, 4.6, 4, 3.6, 4.8, 4.2, 3.8, 4, 
    2, 4.6, 3.8, 4.6, 4.4, 4.8, NaN, 4.6, NaN, 4, 4.4, NaN, 4.2, 
    3.6, 4.6, 4.4, 5, 4.6, NaN, 5, 4.2, 3.4), Rt4 = c(4.2, 3.6, 
    4.4, 4, 5, NaN, 4.4, 4, 4, NaN, 4, 4.2, 4, 4, NaN, 5, 4.6, 
    4, 4, 1.8, 4.6, 4.2, 4.8, 4.6, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 4.4, 
    NaN, 4.2, 3.4, 4.4, NaN, 3.8, NaN, 4, 5, NaN, NaN), Rt5 = c(3.4, 
    3.2, 4.6, 3.6, 5, 3.6, 4.4, 3.8, 4, 4, 4.2, 4.4, NaN, 2.8, 
    3.4, 5, 4.4, 4.2, 3.6, 4.2, 4.2, 4, 4.4, 5, NaN, NaN, 4, 
    NaN, 4, 3.8, 3.2, 4.2, 3.4, NaN, 4.4, NaN, 5, 4.4, 4, 4.2, 
    NaN), Rt6 = c(2.4, 3.2, 4.6, NaN, 4.4, NaN, 4.4, 3.6, 2.4, 
    4.2, 4, 4.4, 3.4, 3.6, 3.4, 4.4, NaN, 4, 3.2, 2.2, 4.4, NaN, 
    4.4, 5, NaN, NaN, NaN, 3.2, 4.4, 4, 3, 4.6, 3, NaN, 4.25, 
    NaN, 4.2, 3.6, 3.8, 4.4, NaN), Rt7 = c(3, 3.2, NaN, NaN, 
    4.2, 4, 4.4, 3.6, 2.8, 4, 4.4, 4.6, 3.8, 2.8, NaN, 4.8, 4.2, 
    4, 3.6, 3, 4.8, 4.2, 4.2, 5, NaN, NaN, 4.4, 4.4, 4, 3.2, 
    NaN, NaN, 1, 4.4, 4.2, 3.6, 3.8, 4, 1.4, 4.6, 2.8), Rt8 = c(3.2, 
    3.2, 4.6, NaN, 4.4, 3.4, 4.2, 4, 3.8, 4, 4.2, 3.8, 3.6, 1.4, 
    NaN, NaN, 4.6, NaN, 3.6, 4.2, 4, 4.4, 4.4, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
    4.6, 4.2, 4.2, 3.2, 4, 3.6, 3, 4.6, 4.8, 3.6, 4.2, 4.2, 2.2, 
    5, NaN), Rt9 = c(3.2, NaN, NaN, NaN, 3.8, 4.2, 3.6, NaN, 
    3, 4, 3.8, 4.2, 3.8, 2.2, NaN, 5, 4.8, NaN, 3.4, 2.8, 5, 
    NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 4.4, NaN, 4, 3, NaN, 1, 3, NaN, 
    NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.6, NaN, NaN), Rt10 = c(3.6, NaN, 4.2, 
    NaN, NaN, NaN, 4, 3.4, 3.2, 4, 4, 4, 3.6, 2, NaN, NaN, 4.4, 
    4, 3.4, 1.8, 4.2, 3.8, 3.8, 4, NaN, NaN, NaN, 4.2, 3.8, 4.2, 
    4.2, 3.2, 1.6, 4.6, NaN, 4, 5, 4, 3.4, NaN, 3.6), Rt11 = c(4, 
    3.2, 4.2, NaN, 3.6, 4.6, 4.4, 4.6, 4.2, NaN, NaN, 4.6, 4.6, 
    4.2, NaN, 5, 4.6, 4.2, 4, 4, 4.6, 4.4, 3.6, 5, NaN, NaN, 
    NaN, NaN, 4.4, 4.6, NaN, NaN, 1.6, 4.6, 5, NaN, 5, 4, NaN, 
    NaN, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, -41L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .Names = c("Type", "Student", "Rt1", "Rt2", "Rt3", 
"Rt4", "Rt5", "Rt6", "Rt7", "Rt8", "Rt9", "Rt10", "Rt11"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000007b30788>)
```

Comment: The print output and the `dput` output both are pointing to the fact that you are working with an item of class:data.table (not data.frame except by inheritance.)  MikeH. apparently understands this but it would be more useful question for future possibly more naive users if you made this more obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to melt your dataset then merge on the `weeks`:

```
weeks_time <- data.frame(timePeriod=c("Rt1", "Rt2", "Rt3", "Rt4", "Rt5", "Rt6", "Rt7", "Rt8", "Rt9", "Rt10", "Rt11"),
                    weeks=c("Jan11","Jan25","Feb1","Feb8", "Feb15", "Mar1", "Mar8", "Mar15","Mar22", "Mar29", "Apr5"))

pulse_m <- melt(pulse, id.vars = c("Student", "Type"), variable.name = "timePeriod", value.name = "Rating")
merge(pulse_m, weeks_time)

  #   timePeriod Student Type Rating weeks
  #1:        Rt1  789331  SNR    3.6 Jan11
  #2:        Rt1  805933  SNR    4.8 Jan11
  #3:        Rt1  826523  SNR    4.4 Jan11
  #4:        Rt1  832929  SNR    3.8 Jan11
  #5:        Rt1  838607  SNR    5.0 Jan11
 #---                                     
#447:       Rt11  981621  FYS    5.0  Apr5
#448:       Rt11  952797  FYS    4.0  Apr5
#449:       Rt11  965873  FYS    NaN  Apr5
#450:       Rt11  967416  FYS    NaN  Apr5
#451:       Rt11  975424  FYS    NaN  Apr5
```

This allows you to avoid any for looping.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df.weeks <- data.frame(timePeriod = c("Rt1", "Rt2", "Rt3", "Rt4", "Rt5", "Rt6", "Rt7", "Rt8", "Rt9", "Rt10", "Rt11"),
                       week = c("Jan11","Jan25","Feb1","Feb8", "Feb15", "Mar1", "Mar8", "Mar15","Mar22", "Mar29", "Apr5"))


pulse <- pulse %>% 
         gather(timePeriod, Rating, Rt1:Rt11) %>% 
         merge(df.weeks) %>%
         select(Student, Type, timePeriod, week, Rating)
```